# Highlighting current page link using JSP

Tags: html, css, jsp

I have a jsp page with some links in it.

```
<div id="menu">
    <span></span>
    <ul class="nav">
        <li class="top_border"></li>                
        <li class="item3"><a href="">Polos</a></li>
        <li class="item4"><a href="">Blouses</a></li>
        <li class="item5"><a href="">Sweaters</a></li>
        <li class="item6"><a href="">Pants </a></li>
        <li class="item7"><a href="">Jeans</a></li>
        <li class="item8"><a href="">Jackets</a></li>
        <li class="item9"><a href="">Footwear</a></li>  
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have written style for this one as below

```
ul.nav li a:hover {
    background: #ebebeb url(images/border.png) no-repeat;
    color: red;
    padding: 7px 15px 7px 30px;
}
```

When I hover it, the color changes and when I click that link the respective page for that link opens. After that it becomes normal as before. I want to apply that style on the link of the **current** page. How can I do it? I am using JSP behind.

Answer (score 12):

The way for that is doing it in JSP :

```
<div id="menu">
    <span></span>
    <ul class="nav">
        <li class="top_border"></li>                
        <li class="item3${pageContext.request.requestURI eq 'path/polos.jsp' ? ' active' : ''}"><a href="path/polis.jsp">Polos</a></li>
        <li class="item4${pageContext.request.requestURI eq 'path/blouses.jsp' ? ' active' : ''}"><a href="path/polis.jsp">Blouses</a></li>
        <li class="item5${pageContext.request.requestURI eq 'path/sweaters.jsp' ? ' active' : ''}"><a href="path/sweaters.jsp">Polos</a></li>
        <li class="item6${pageContext.request.requestURI eq 'path/pants.jsp' ? ' active' : ''}"><a href="path/sweaters.jsp">Pants</a></li>
        <li class="item7${pageContext.request.requestURI eq 'path/jeans.jsp' ? ' active' : ''}"><a href="path/sweaters.jsp">Jeans</a></li>
        <li class="item8${pageContext.request.requestURI eq 'path/jackets.jsp' ? ' active' : ''}"><a href="path/sweaters.jsp">Jackets</a></li>
        <li class="item9${pageContext.request.requestURI eq 'path/footwear.jsp' ? ' active' : ''}"><a href="path/sweaters.jsp">Footwear</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

You will have to just be sure you have the right paths. I suggest that you output directly `${pageContext.request.requestURI}` in your page just to see what you get and adjust comparisions accordingly.

After that you only have to declare one CSS class :

```
.active > a
{
    color: red;
}
```

I also **suggest** you to have all your links in some `List` and do an iteration to render your menu since you don't need to repeat that code. You have JSP behind, use it!

Comment: this is what the OP asked for. kudos!

Comment: @AhmadAlfy Exactly :) but I think he doesn't know yet :)

Comment: Yeah. He misused words like `style` and `visited` and used `html` as a tag. People should go beyond the words and explain the concepts for the newbie developers. We should take time to read briefly instead of rushing to the votes. I never used jsp and cannot verify if your answer is correct. I upvoted it cause you got the question. I modified the question title to make sense but people are still posting CSS solutions and DOM manipulators!

Comment: Deleted my answer in favor of this one.

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie good solution, but if requestURI is same for 2 different menus, then how we can differentiate (because in my case its highlighting both menus) ?

Comment: @Deven well, if you have 2 menu items pointing the current page, both are "active", if for example you have top menu and footer menu, and you are in home page, both home buttons will be active which is valid.

Comment: I mean my both menu are on top and pointing same jsp page with different data, so there should be one menu active at a time when i select, but it making both active or highlighting ?

Comment: You should post a new question, will be easier

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
ul.nav li a:visited {
    color: red;/* you can keep your original color*/
}
```

Alternative jquery solution

```
$('.nav li a').on('click', function() {
    $('.active').removeClass('activelink');
    $(this).addClass('activelink');
});
```

Now you can add css

```
.activelink{color:red;}
```

Comment: The question is not about `a:visited`. It's about highlighting the active page using a class. The original poster misused the words `active` and `style` while all what he needs is to modify his jsp code

Comment: Also, by way of a reminder, css comments are supposed to be enclosed in /* */. Using // can mess up your stylesheet.

Comment: actually original question asked about visited link

Comment: i need is, the link i clicked(will be highlighted as per my style) to stay until i click on another link

Comment: In the original question it is also stated `... that visited link to stay till i click some other link...` so Until, not forever.

Comment: for that you can simply use :active. The :active selector is used to select and style the active link. A link becomes active when you click on it.

Comment: @edd When he will come back in any page, all visited link will be **active** styled with your method, until he has a mouse-down event on links.