# Dynamically set list item active in bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jsp

I have a menu file (menu.jsp) that is included in two other files current.jsp and something.jsp. I want to dynamically set the list item to active using class="active", depending on if I am in current.jsp or something.jsp.I want to do have this logic in the menu. Can I do this by only using html and css? (I would prefer to do this without javascript)

menu.jsp:

```
<ul id="navbar_menu" class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
    <li id="current"><a href="current">Current</a></li>
    <li i="something"><a href="something">Something</a></li>
</ul>
```

menu.css 
What should I include here??????

current.jsp

```
<body id="current">
<jsp:include page="menu.jsp" />
</body>
```

Comment: You need either JavaScript or JSP

Comment: Okay. Thank you. How do I do this?

Comment: Here's the JSP way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17017572/highlighting-current-page-link-using-jsp

Comment: I am writing ${pageContext.request.requestURI} in my jsp-file but I only see the text on the screen. What should i do to make it work?

Comment: Does anybody know this?